# Where does keytool command logs?

Tags: logging, keytool

I want to know in which file keytool command logs all the information.

i.e when i execute below command :

```
-keytool -import -file ca-certificate.cer -alias sample -keystore /root/keystore.jks
```

I couldn't find any log information, also I want to add log information for any certificate imports.